# Как получить поля с ближайшим значением от числа sql

Tags: mysql, sql, cms, opencart

Здравствуйте.
Суть задачи получить товары с близкой ценой от текущего товара (Рекомендуемые товары). Сайт на OpenCart.

К примеру текущая цена товара 50$, и нужно что бы показывались товары с самой близкой ценой, а не 100$ и не 10$.

Нашел запрос, получающий id товаров с рубрики. Однако нужно получить близкие товары по цене. 
Запрос:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(p2c.product_id) FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category` p2c LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "product` p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store` p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE p2c.category_id IN ('" . $category_list . "') AND p2c.product_id != '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " . $limit);
```

Цена находится в таблице `product` и столбец `price`

Comment: А если $100 и $10 являются самыми близки значениями, это считается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть задачи сводится к трем подзадачам:

1. Получить товар с ценой больше текущей.
2. Получить товар с ценой меньше текущей.
3. Объединить оба результата в одно решение через union all.

   ```
   select ...
   where  ...
         p.price > current_price order by p.price limit 1
   union all 
   select ...
   where  ...
         p.price < current_price order by p.price desc limit 1
   ```

Если надо еще как-то ограничить, то можно еще использовать математические операции, о чем тоже не следует забывать. К примеру если цена выше не должна превышать 10% от текущей стоимости.

```
    and p.price > current_price and p.price < (current_price + current_price * 0.1)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Задачу можно решить в рамках одного `SELECT`. Достаточно добавить такую сортировку:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN price < 'ваша стоимость'
      THEN price + (('ваша стоимость' - price) * 2)
      ELSE price
  END ASC
LIMIT N
```